# How can a Terminal Services aware application retrieve the user's private Windows directory?

Tags: c#, terminal-services

The documentation for GetWindowsDirectory says:

- TS-Aware applications get the *actual* Windows directory.
- Non-TS-Aware applications get the current user's "private" Windows directory.

So, I am working on a C# class library that needs to be TS-Aware, because I cannot require all apps using this library to be non-TS-Aware. The C# default is to be TS-Aware.

I need to drop INI files into the Windows directory to communicate with a legacy App that is NOT TS-Aware. This works without difficulty in a regular user, but not in a Terminal Services session.

Under Terminal Services:

- The Legacy App uses the INI file in the user's "private" Windows directory.
- The C# library uses the INI file in the system Windows directory.

I need to:

1. Detect when running under Terminal Services.  I can do this by checking the `SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession` flag.
2. From a TS-Aware process, locate the user's "private" Windows directory.  I can find no documentation that tells me how to do this.

Comment: I answered incorrectly. I was confused. I also altered your subject in the hopes that the next person won't get confused.

Comment: I found this question asked only a few minutes ago while searching: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverTS/thread/bba6b4cf-d7e5-4eb3-955f-2e2481c17d87. Is JeffB also JBrophy?

Comment: Same same.  MSDN usually gets a faster MS-approved response, but StackOverflow sometimes gets a better non-MS solution for the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is always under the user folder in the windows sub directory, so:

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), "windows");
```

Comment: FYI: Microsoft's official answer is "Don't do that."  They recommend refactoring all code (legacy and new) to use the per-user "Application Data" folder instead.